# How can I access a variable from another file in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to access a variable called `_country`from another file in dart, but an error occured: `The getter '_country' isn't defined for the type 'CurrentCountry'.`

Here's the code where the variable I want to access is(in another file):

```
class CurrentCountry {
  static String _country = 'All';
}
```

And here's the code where I want to access the variable:

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchWorldData() async {
    Response activeResponse = await get(Uri.parse(
        'https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/${CurrentCountry._country}'));
    return json.decode(activeResponse.body);
  }
```

If you can help me, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the underscore of the variable.

> *If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it’s private to its
> library*

Reference here: Dart language [Important concepts](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts)